# How to compile scintilla in windows?

Tags: c++

I never compiled any open source project in Windows. I want to compile Scintilla on windows in Visual Studio or in any other way. Pleas write a step by step instruction to compile it.

I have googled for last 2 week but could not get any tutorial/guide. Please help.

I tried to compile in windows as per the instruction provided in README file in scintilla source  and got following error.

D:\scintilla\win32>nmake -f scintilla.mak

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility   Version 7.00.8882
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1988-2000. All rights reserved.

```
    rc -fo.\ScintRes.res ScintRes.rc
```

ScintRes.rc(5) : fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h'.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'rc' : return code '0x1'
Stop.

My OS is windows xp. I am using visual studio 2005 and also have installed Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2.

Comment: The download contains a file called README which explains how to build Scintilla on Windows. Try the instructions there and post back with any problems you have. Describe what specific problems you have instead of just asking for instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from that error message you're using the standard Windows command line. Use the Visual Studio command prompt instead, it sets up important paths and evironment variables:

*Start menu* **>** *programs* **>** *Microsoft Visual Studio 2005* **>** *Visual Studio Tools* **>** *Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt*.

Navigate to the scintilla dir and run nmake like you did before.

That being said I ran into lots of obscure error messages with nmake so I ended up creating a VS project like this:

***Note**: this builds a static library with lexers, adjust as you see fit.*

1. Create a new project for a static library
2. Add everything that's in *lexers*, *lexlib*, *src* and *win32*
3. Add `STATIC_BUILD` and `SCI_LEXER` to the preprocessor directives if you
   want a static library and lexer support.
4. Add *src*, *lexlib* and *include* to the additional include directories.
5. If you don't need lexers or only some of them, delete what you don't need inside *lexers* and run *src/LexGen.py*